# Reading SyndicationFeed in background

Tags: push-notification, rss, background-task

```
Uri uri = new Uri( feedUri);
            SyndicationClient client = new SyndicationClient();
            SyndicationFeed currentFeed = await client.RetrieveFeedAsync(uri);
            XmlDocument toastXml = ToastNotificationManager.GetTemplateContent(ToastTemplateType.ToastImageAndText03);
            XmlNodeList toastTextElement = toastXml.GetElementsByTagName("text");
            toastTextElement[0].AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode("Working"));
            ToastNotification toast = new ToastNotification(toastXml);
            ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().Show(toast);
```

nothing is being executed after RetrieveFeedAsync.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add deferal to your Running Background

```
public async void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
    {

        BackgroundTaskDeferral deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();

        //YOUR CODE GOES HERE           

        deferral.Complete();

    }
```